# linearity of a time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, python, kalman-filter

I am currently trying to correct forecast data using Kalman filter (python). I do not know where to start.
I wanted to know how can I do a test to Know if my time series is linear or non linear? Is there a test?

Comment: First, you should state what you exactly mean by linear time series. Linear can mean pretty much (linear in the parameters, linear in the applied basis functions, simple linear regression with each predictor separated, etc.)

Comment: I mean to see if we have a linear time series or not. In order to know if we need to apply it with Kalman Filter or Unscented Kalman Filter

Comment: That depends on your model for the states. Is it linear or nonlinear? If nonlinear, could it be reasonable approximated as a linear process?

Comment: Hi Greg,that's my question how do I know if a time series is linear?

Comment: Do you know something about the system or are you just attempting to us e for "black-box" outputs?  More information about what kind of data you have here could be helpful.  (In any case, the question seems to be whether the time-series can be modeled as generated by a linear-Gaussian dynamic system, rather than "is it linear")